# A 2D distance measure that gives weightage to the angle between the two points?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, angle

```
       n1     n8     n7


    n2        c         n6



       n3     n4     n5
```

Assume that all neighbors `n`*i* are (Euclidean) equidistant to candidate `c`.

Is there a distance measure that would yield a smaller distance between a candidate and a neighbor if the angle between them (w.r.t y-axis) approaches either 0 or 90 degrees? (`n2` and `n6` would be at 0 degrees and `n8` and `n4` would be at 90 degrees)

In the example above, the distances need to be like:

`[ dist(c, n2) = dist(c, n4) = dist(c, n6) = dist(c, n8) ] < [ dist(c, n1) = dist(c, n3) = dist(c, n5) = dist(c, n7) ]`

Comment: something like $x(90-x)$?

Comment: Try *Manhattan distance*. To find the distance between 2 points, it assumes they are on a grid, and counts the number of steps (horizontal or vertical) needed to go from one point to the other.